# How can I make Beautiful Soup filter results based on numbers in a link

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project where I need to extract a links from over 1000 pages. My issue is that every page has lots of links I don't need and I am struggling to filter them.

I have tried making the link more specific but that eliminates the results I need as well. I have also tried using regular expressions, however I lack experience with them so I may have used them wrong.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
import re

only_a_tags = SoupStrainer("a", href=re.compile("scp-^[0-5000]+$"))

for i in range(680, 690):
    URL = "http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-"+ str (i)
    response = requests.get(URL)
    html_doc = response.text

    print(BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser", parse_only=only_a_tags).prettify())
```

I need this to print out any links formatted like this http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-[Numbers here]. It does not need to print the whole thing, just scp-[Numbers here].

Right now it does not print out anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change regex to `scp-\d+`, it will print your links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
import re

only_a_tags = SoupStrainer("a", href=re.compile("scp-\d+"))

for i in range(680, 690):
    URL = "http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-" + str(i)
    response = requests.get(URL)
    html_doc = response.text

    print(BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser", parse_only=only_a_tags).prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<a href="/scp-679">
 SCP-679
</a>
<a href="/scp-681">
 SCP-681
</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/forum/t-146364/scp-680" id="discuss-button">
 Discuss (19)
</a>
<a href="/scp-680">
 SCP-680
</a>
<a href="/scp-682">
 SCP-682

... and so on.
```